# if window is popup

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to determine if the current window is a popup? This is what I have right now but for some reason it is not working. I am trying to make sure that certain pages are only shown in popup window.

```
if(!opener)
window.location = 'error.php';
```

The value of opener is [object DOMWindow] even though the window is not popup.

Comment: Do you get an error when it doesn't work?  what is the value of `opener` when you think it should work but it doesn't?

Comment: The value of opener is [object DOMWindow] even though the window is not popup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're opening popup windows yourself- set a flag:

```
var myWindow = window.open(...);
myWindow.isPopup = true;
```

then, in your popup window, check for the flag:

```
if (!window.isPopup) {
    window.location = 'error.php';
}
```