# Check whether a window is Popup or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question is not the duplicate of [if window is popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963240/if-window-is-popup) , But a similar one.

I am developing a extension which injects scripts to all web pages. I need to detect whether the window is popup or not.

Note:
I am not the one who is opening the popup window, So the above solution won't work.

Comment: is your popup is window.open()?

Comment: No, Am not the one who is opening the popup. So I have no relation with window.open()

Comment: then which kind of popup you are using?

Comment: define "pop-up", because browsers have the option to open pop-ups as new tabs. would you consider a "programmatically opened tab" also a pop-up?

Comment: In that case, what really defines a popup pertaining to the distinction needed by your extension? Is it just features that the current window has?

Comment: this is what I meant by popup window http://i.imgur.com/Yuida.png

Comment: @QuintinRobinson My scripts modify the page, I don't what my script to modify the popup window.

Comment: @Jeevan To an outside application what really distinguishes a "popup" window from any other window? Isn't it really arbitrary?

Comment: Pop-up windows have a parent "opener", pages opened from another page (like using `target=_blank`) do not maintain a relationship with the orgin window.

Answer (score 41):

I've found that some browsers will set window.opener to window in certain cases. This is the most reliable popup check that I am using right now.

```
if (window.opener && window.opener !== window) {
  // you are in a popup
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this one is the ticket.

Comment: obligatory "this should be the accepted answer". Another addition though; if you maybe know the name of the window from the second argument of window.open, you can use this: `window.open('example.org', 'the-window-name')` can be checked with `if (window.opener && … window.name === 'the-window-name')`

Comment: This does not work if you close the "opener" browser window. Then `window.opener` is `null`. The same thing happens when the user is redirected to another domain ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712160/12534)).

Comment: Christian Davén - Interesting find. For the part about closing the opener, maybe you could immediately store the initial value of the conditional in a variable.

Comment: This is not a silver bullet. As noted in a few of the comments, `window.opener` will return `true` **even if not a popup window** if the window was opened with `window.open` and even a few other cases. Please be aware of this.

Comment: It's doesn't work, if you use relative links, e.g. <a href='/profile'>...</a>. React router uses this kind of links under hood.

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari, I am seeing `window.opener === window` when in a popup.

Comment: Doesn't work if opener is closed before the check because it is set null when parent is closed.

Comment: @BrobicVripiat Try caching the value in the popup window immediately when the popup is opened. `window.BrobicVripiatPopup = window.opener && window.opener !== window;`

Answer (score 21):

The following worked for me when testing in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE8. It worked for a window created useing window.open() or target=_blank.

```
if (window.opener) {
    alert('inside a pop-up window or target=_blank window');
} else if (window.top !== window.self) {
    alert('inside an iframe');
} else {
    alert('this is a top level window');
}
```

Comment: window.opener is undefined in IE if the popup has another origin.

Comment: This will not help in the special case when the popup contains an iframe and the script checking window.opener is running inside the iframe.

Comment: I'm getting `window.opener` as true for a normal page (not popup via window.open). I'm using latest Chrome.

Comment: not working when do refresh the popup window by pressing F5

Comment: Doesn't work if opener is closed.

Answer (score 5):

`window.locationbar.visible` not necessarily only for a popup, but can help detecting if the user can change the location manually via location bar...

Comment: Much better to look at `window.menubar.visible`, as in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14954591/12534).

Comment: For a Chrome extension, I needed to distinguish a popup window from the same code loaded in an browser action popup. I assumed `menubar.visible` would be `false` in both cases, since neither kind of popup shows a menubar. But it's actually `true` in the browser action case, so that can be used to distinguish these two kinds of extension popups.

Answer (score 3):

I use this code to determine a popup window

```
(window.opener && window.opener !== window && !window.menubar.visible)
```

Comment: The `window.opener &&` bit is unnecessary, since if `opener` is `null`, it won't equal `window`.

Comment: `window.opener &&` bit is necessary. Otherwise, when `window.opener` is null, it will not equal window and it will think it's a popup when it's not

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Safari.  I am seeing that window.opener === window, even in a popup

Comment: rcbevans - it should be window.opener === window in a popup

Answer (score 2):

The following statement will be true if window is a popup window or subframe:

```
 window.parent != window
```

Comment: This is retuning false for me for both a popup and for a window opened via normal `<a target="blank">` which I don't think OP is checking for.

Comment: I don't think that using <a taget="blank"> creates a popup window. In my understanding popup windows opened with window.open(). Which browser did you use? I've tried with Chrome

Comment: I know that they don't create popups. But I'm saying your test comes back with the same result for windows opened by `target` and by `window.open` Also on chrome.

Comment: "I need to detect whether the window is ***popup*** or not." - Original question asks about popup window, not hyperlink with target attribute.

Comment: Dude, that is exactly what I'm saying.  My testing shows that `window.parent != window` returns the same result for both `window.open()` and windows/tabs opened via `target="_blank"`. Therefore, it would be a false positive for a popup if it was a new window from a `target="_blank"`, which the OP doesn't want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10303/discussion-between-maksym-kozlenko-and-anthony)

Answer (score 2):

I was implementing 'close' button for popup window screen and 'cancel' button for '_self' window in "Typescript/Nodejs" and believe it will work for JavaScript as well.
So I needed to determine if screen is opened in a popup

```
if(window.opener || window.history.length === 1) 
     isPopupWindow = true;
else 
   isPopupWindow = false;
```

"window.opener" works for almost all the browsers but having issue with IE so to handle IE issue I used "window.history.length".

Comment: `|| window.history.length === 1` will cause this to be true on any newly opened window, regardless if it's a poopup or not

Answer (score 2):

```
if (window.menubar.visible) 
    // Not Popup
else
    // Popup
```

`window.opener` is `true` when a window is a popup but only if the opener window is still open, if it has been closed it is `false`, so it won't always work for determining if a window is a popup

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check if the opener is NOT undefined? a popup has an opener while a regular page hasn't.

```
if (window.opener != null)
```

Comment: You should check `window.opener` against `null`, not `undefined`.

Comment: Because if you close the opener before the check the opener will become null so not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

For me, i was implementing a Logout screen that could be shown in a window popup via window.open(..) or from a link within a single page.

I needed to determine:

1) if my Logout screen is within a popup, then:

```
event.preventDefault();
window.close();
```

2) otherwise use the browser back function..

```
window.history.back();
```

My solution:
If the page is within a popup, in my case it has a window page history of 1:

```
event.preventDefault();
if (window.history.length === 1) {
    window.close();
} else {
    window.history.back();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a sure fire method, but typically a popup using `window.open()` does not direct to a new URL, so both windows will have the same href. Therefore, in many cases:

```
window.location.href == window.opener.location.href
```

will be true for a popup. So you could do:

```
var isPopup = (window.location.href == window.opener.location.href);
```

Like I said, this works in my limited tests, so there may be some feedback that shows where this won't be reliable.

Comment: widnow.open() can open blank window and have the conent created with JavaScirpt or have any URL, both internal or external set (obviously you won't be able to control popup window with another doamin URL due to same domain policy).

Comment: Right. If the URL is specified, this won't work. But usually when the url is specified, under a situation such as the OP's, he' would probably want whatever code injection to happen anyway. Not for sure, but more often than not.

Comment: just to add you have a mistake if window.location.href == window.opener.location.href is true than its not popup

Comment: Agree with @AmirBar, I've extended this example with:
`isPopup = (window.opener!=undefined);`

Answer (score -1):

The best way, is simply to check the window width, then try to resize the window width in a pixel or two, and then check if the current width equals or not to the one before the resize

in other words, if you succeeded to resize the window, you're probably inside a popup.

good luck.