# Is there a way to determine if the browser window is a popup, or just a new window using target="_blank"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, popup

I'm maintaining a large application. In some areas, I have to check if the current window is a popup (opened using window.open()) or a new window (a new tab or window opened using target="_blank").

Here is an example of my problem:

```
    function CancelOutOfPage(cancelPath) {
        if (cancelPath != null && cancelPath != "" && window.opener == null) {
            location.href = cancelPath;
        } else if (referrerUrl != "" && window.opener == null) {
            // Just go back
            location.href = referrerUrl;
        } else {
            // It is a popup, close it.
            // MY PROBLEM IS HERE. IF THE WINDOW IS NOT A POPUP, BUT A AN OPENED PAGE
            // THE WHOLE WINDOW WILL CLOSE
            window.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check out this [Check whether a window is Popup or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240398/check-whether-a-window-is-popup-or-not)

Comment: @ZuraSekhniashvili I did, but if I'm understanding this correctly, we can determine if the window is "'inside a pop-up window or target=_blank window'" if the window.opener is not null. But How do I check if I'm just inside a popup window, or just inside a target=_blank?

Comment: @VinShahrdar Is the new `window` opened from you application?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, from many different sources.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set a global variable when you open the popup, and then you know it's a popup if variable is a truthy value - if it's `undefined` it will be `false`:

**In the calling page:**

```
var popupWindow = window.open(page);
popupWindow.isPopup = true;
```

**In the new window:**

```
if (window.isPopup) { 
    window.close();
}
```

## Update:

You could alternatively set the name of the `window` when you open with a popup. The [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) function takes a second parameter for the name, followed by optional window features.

**In the calling page:**

```
window.open("test.html", "Test Popup");
```

**In the new window:**

```
if (window.name.length) { 
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that there are possibly hundreds of window opens in the entire system. I was wondering if there is a way to handle this using minimal effort. Would checking for window.name work? I might be wrong, but window.name is only set when we open a new popup.

Comment: @VinShahrdar Yes, that should work too. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can give flag on window when you open it.

```
//in window from which you open new window
var w = window.open('');
w.someFlag = true;

//in opened window
console.log(window.someFlag);
if (window.someFlag){
    //do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `name` of the new `window` by providing second parameter to `window.open()`, e.g.;

```
 var w = window.open("url", "__blank__")
```

at opened `window`,

```
 if (this.name === "__blank__") {/*do stuff*/} else {/*do other stuff*/}
```