# How to detect that my window is open in popup

Tags: javascript, window.open

How to detect that my window is open in popup?
I'm need detect when my site opened in popup window (window.open, not in target=_blank window)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether a window is Popup or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240398/check-whether-a-window-is-popup-or-not)

Comment: This is super simple to find before asking a question: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+How+to+detect+that+my+window+is+open+in+popup

Comment: Using listeners can help you, maybe you can [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030893/711143).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.opener)
   {
    alert('the page is inside a pop-up window or target=_blank');
   }
 else
   {
    alert('Not a pop-up or target=_blank');
 }
```

It's not possible to know if a window is a `Pop-up` or `_blank` if you don't have the control over the pop-up attributes.

My hint to maybe make this possible would be to read the parent window html and look for the window.open('yourpage') script being (true or false).

Best regards

Comment: No. i need detect popup window, but no target=_blank

Comment: Do you have control over the window.open params? If you do, you can set the title or other params like width or height in order to check if it is your Popup.

Comment: My page open from other site. if she open from target=_blank this is good. If she open from window.open this is bad

Comment: I've made some clarifications on the answer. Please check it out. :)